# How python handles non-UTF-8 code? Removing part of working code leads to encoding error

Tags: python

I have Python behaving very strange.
Updated question to get rid of all unrelated code:

My new file has only this content:

```
renamingDict = {'ID':'lead_id','Статус':'status','Название лида':'title','Имя':'name','Дата создания':'created_at','Источник':'source','Рабочий телефон':'phones','Ответственный':'manager','Дата изменения':'changed_at','Комментарий':'lead_comment','Дата экскурсии, ожидаемая':'exc_date','Ссылка':'link','ID брони/заявки':'res_id','ID экскурсии':'lead_exc_id','ID организатора':'lead_org_id'}
```

it gives error:

`SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xd0' in file .\lead_analysis.py on line 10, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details`

but it WON'T give error if I add new element to dictionary's source. After 'lead_comment',
I will add 'UTM Source':'',
and I would have:

```
renamingDict = {'ID':'lead_id','Статус':'status','Название лида':'title','Имя':'name','Дата создания':'created_at','Источник':'source','Рабочий телефон':'phones','Ответственный':'manager','Дата изменения':'changed_at','Комментарий':'lead_comment','UTM Source':'','Дата экскурсии, ожидаемая':'exc_date','Ссылка':'link','ID брони/заявки':'res_id','ID экскурсии':'lead_exc_id','ID организатора':'lead_org_id'}
```

Which works fine!

I can fix all this by adding

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
```

at the start of my code, but **the most weird part is that I encounter the error after REMOVING independent part of working code**.

How can python think that dictionary of 17 elements is fine, but give **'encoding'** error when I remove one element from the dictionary, without even proceeding further. It understood my code with extra symbols, how can it not understand it now?

The issue seems so absurd that I really want someone to help me understand how this works, even though I have workaround with

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
```

More so, my "buggy" line with dictionary works without errors if I just make a new line in my dictionary listing

Comment: Add `encoding` param into `open` function, I think, the problem is in this one

Comment: Please show the **exact** first 10+ lines of each version of the code - you claim that an error occurs there, but you didn't show us. I would suspect a quoting problem...

Comment: You only gives hints. Can you try to provide a [mvce] with a working source file and another not working when removing some element.

Comment: OK here is MVCE:
renamingDict = {'ID':'lead_id','Статус':'status','Название лида':'title','Имя':'name','Дата создания':'created_at','Источник':'source','Рабочий телефон':'phones','Ответственный':'manager','Дата изменения':'changed_at','Комментарий':'lead_comment','Дата экскурсии, ожидаемая':'exc_date','Ссылка':'link','ID брони/заявки':'res_id','ID экскурсии':'lead_exc_id','ID организатора':'lead_org_id'}

Comment: above is FULL CONTENT of new file which gives error. The error does not occur if we add  'UTM Source':'' after element [lead_comment]

Comment: This error happens when running this with Python 2, it's OK with Python 3. Are you really sure that you want to use such an old, no longer supported version of Python?? Or is it just that you think that you used Python 3, and your system uses Python 2 without your consent?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I am using Python 3.7.3

Comment: Actually, you're not. Your code gets run by some Python 2 that is present on your system.

Comment: Oh.. I have to look into that, thank you! I mean, if I use windows shell and start "python" it shows 3 version. My buggy example happens when I run my source code in shell using this command: python filename.py

Comment: I am now confused about how my windows decides to use python 2, in above scenario

Answer (score -1):

So you found the solution yourself: Specifying the encoding

My theory for why would be:
UTF-8 uses 1 byte for some characters and multiple for others. So adding a few non-ascii characters that don't produce an error by themselves can bring the parser out of sync with the character count and thus cause an error later.

If you want to test it, put your code back in and randomly add a few russian characters to see if it starts working again all of the sudden.

Comment: @Алексей Pretty sure my answer is (at least somewhat) correct, did you try it out?

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Unfortunately I was focused on another approach (you can see in post comments), and current state of this issue FOR ME is how to stop my Windows from using Python 2 when I run "python myFile.py" in Shell...